# Dealing with more number of Pannel s in Swings

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have many panel in one screen. Each panel has buttons, labels and etc. So how to hide and unhide every panel?

```
    JPannel jp1=new JPannel();
    jp1.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("need to show 1st pannel data");
    headerframe.add(jp1);
    JPannel  jp2=new JPannel();
    jp2.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("need to show 2nd pannel along with the 1st pannel data");
    headerframe.add(jp2);
```

here first can only work the content which is there in 2nd panel is not coming so can any one help me out?

Comment: Consider [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: .....`JPannel`?? But yes, @trashgod's comment is way better than bcsb1001's answer. Use a CardLayout to swap views. But also, please when posting code, try not to be sloppy as can lead to misunderstanding of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but going by your question about how to hide and unhide panels, use the `setVisible()` method:

```
aPanel.setVisible(false); // hides the panel
aPanel.setVisible(true); // shows it again
```